How to pass docker-compose.yml
docker compose command takes -f argument that allows you to pass the alternative docker-compose.yml file location.
How can I do this using environment variables so that I do not need to repeat -f every time on a command line?

You can set COMPOSE_FILE environment variable.
export COMPOSE_FILE=my-alternative-docker-compose.yml

Now docker compose will default to this file instead of docker-compose.yml on every run.
